# Audio recording timing does not match external timer

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I am recording audio on Android device and need to get precise timestamps of the ongoing recording. These timestamps will be related to some other data during post-processing of the recorded file. Currently I am getting these timestamps as follows by creating new timer thread:

```
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startHTime;
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

Right after I start audio recording I reset the timer:

```
mRecorder.start();
startHTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
```

After I finish the recording I destroy `handler` which takes the timestamp and does some computations and kill the timer:

```
mRecorder.stop();
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

This is how `handler` is defined:

```
handler = new Handler();
handlerDelay = 100; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        MeasuredPoint point = getMeasuredPoint(); // this part records the timestamp and does some intense computations to calcluate 3D points.
        handler.postDelayed(this, handlerDelay);
    }
}, handlerDelay);
```

However, my last timestamp has the value which is always around 300ms higher than the duration of the audio recording, but this should not happen as I kill timer thread before stopping the recording. Does anyone know why that happens?

Comment: Why don't you stop the media recorder, then immediately log the timestamp. Then compare to the startHTime. It sounds like you are saying that you are waiting for an onDestroy to do it or something like that. But I typically just log the start time after I call start, then I log the stop time after i call stop.

Comment: Thanks Sam, it makes sense, I will give it a try!